# How can I debug CMakeLists.txt files?

Tags: cmake

How can I debug `CMakeLists.txt` files (at least doing things like listing of variables) other than just using [the `message()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html)?

Comment: Might be helpful, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38869455/2799037

Answer (score 71, accepted):

At the time of originally writing this answer, there were no interactive debugger for CMake, but it was possible to use the flags `-Wdev`, `--debug-output` and `--trace` for additional information and to check the log files `CMakeFiles\CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeFiles\CMakeError.log` which mainly collect outputs of processes called by CMake (for example while checking for presence of a type or header).

[Since version 3.7](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-e-server-improves-visual-studio-and-qt-creator-ides/), CMake now officially supports a "server mode" so integration in IDEs is likely to improve in the near future. Initial support exists both in [Qt Creator](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/11/15/cmake-support-in-qt-creator-and-elsewhere/) and [Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-the-visual-studio-2017-rc-update/)

[Since version 3.27](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debugger), CMake also supports the [Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/) and several IDE vendors (for example [CLion](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2022/10/clion-2022-3-eap-cmake-debugger/) or [Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-debugger-allows-you-to-debug-your-cmake-scripts-and-more/)) now either support or have announced support for CMake debugging. How it works exactly depends on the specific IDE.

Comment: Which one do we use to debug `if` statements in `CmakeList.txt`? `came --debug ...` and `cmake --debug-output ...` are not printing them. In Bash, the equivalent is `bash -x <cmd>`.

Comment: @jww I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to debug, but the output of `--trace` is usually quite extensive (redirect the output to a file!)

Comment: I was trying to debug the script and understand why certain code blocks were not being entered. But I found the problem: `string(STRIP ...)` was broken. Also see [How to strip trailing newline in Cmake variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39496043/). My apologies if you did not know what `bash -x` does.

Comment: You shouldn't just mention checking the logs. You should explain how one goes about checking the logs.

Comment: @ThomasJayRush I added information about the location and content of the log files. Anything beyond that depends on the specific issue.

Comment: Now there are [interactive debuggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75701905/5197544)

Comment: @КоеКто I have updated my answer to reflect the additional debugger support added in CMake 3.27

Answer (score 13):

You can try using the new CMake Script Debugger provided by the [VisualGDB](https://visualgdb.com/) tool. It uses an [open-source fork of CMake](https://github.com/sysprogs/cmake) that supports stepping through CMakeLists.txt files, setting code/data breakpoints, evaluating/changing variables, etc.

There's a detailed step-by-step tutorial on the new debugger [here](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/cmake/debugger/)

Answer (score 12):

I like to use [variable_watch](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) to "debug" my CMakeLists.txt files. Just set in top of my script:

```
variable_watch(SOME_MY_VAR)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using an IDE,

- [CLion announced their CMake debugger on October 25, 2022](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2022/10/clion-2022-3-eap-cmake-debugger/)

  - more docs at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-debug.html.
- [Visual Studio announced their CMake debugger on February 22nd, 2023](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-debugger-allows-you-to-debug-your-cmake-scripts-and-more/)
- [Qt Creator will likely have a CMake debugger in the future](https://www.qt.io/blog/2016/11/15/cmake-support-in-qt-creator-and-elsewhere)
- [Visual Studio's CMake debugger is available in VS Code (announced on Aug 9th, 2023)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-cmake-debugger-in-vs-code-debug-your-cmake-scripts-using-open-source-cmake-debugger/). Docs for it are [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug.md).

Related to that, CMake 3.27 exposes [the `--debugger` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debugger) to enable interactive debugging using the [Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/). See also [the `--cmake-debugger-pipe` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debugger-pipe) and [the `--debugger-dap-log` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debugger-dap-log).

Otherwise,

Pre-CMake v3.26, you can (as suggested by CMake's diagnostic messages) look at the CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log and CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log files in the generated buildsystem's binary/build directory.

[Starting with CMake v3.26, the CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log and CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log files will no longer be supported / created](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.26.html#deprecated-and-removed-features). From the release notes:

> The CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log and CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log files are no longer populated by CMake's built-in modules. [cmake(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#manual:cmake(1)) no longer suggests looking at them after a CMake Error occurs. Information previously logged to those files is instead logged to the [cmake-configure-log(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-configure-log.7.html#manual:cmake-configure-log(7)).

Other CMake debug-related facilities you may find useful include to following:

- To put CMake in a trace mode where it prints all calls made and from where, use [the `--trace` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace) and/or related flags like [`--trace-expand`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace-expand), [`--trace-format`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace-format), [`--trace-source`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace-source) and [`--trace-redirect`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace-redirect).
- To make CMake emit developer warnings meant for CMakeLists.txt authors, use [the `-Wdev` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-Wdev)
- To make CMake emit warnings about deprecated functionality, use [the `-Wdeprecated` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-Wdeprecated)
- To put CMake in a debugging mode where it prints things like stack traces with [`message(SEND_ERROR)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html#command:message) calls, use [the `--debug-output` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debug-output)
- To watch variables for changes, use [the `variable_watch` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html).
- To make CMake warn when uninitialized variables are used, use [the `--warn-uninitialized` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-warn-uninitialized).
- To debug commands that find things like `find_program()`, `find_library()`, `find_file()`, `find_path()`, and `find_package()`, use [the `--debug-find` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debug-find), or for debugging at more granular scopes, [the `CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE.html).
- To debug `try_compile`/`try_run` failures, use [the `--debug-trycompile` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debug-trycompile)
- If you want to do performance profiling of CMake script execution, see the [`--profiling-output`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-profiling-output) and [`--profiling-output`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-profiling-format) flags.

Bonus info: If you want to profile build performance, you can look into the facilities provided by the tools in your toolchain, such as Ninja and Clang. Craig Scott has written an article on the subject here: https://crascit.com/2022/06/24/build-performance-insights/.

Answer (score 5):

There are steveire's [CMake Daemon Tools](https://steveire.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/cmake-daemon-for-user-tools/). I haven't used them myself, but they claim to offer possibilities for introspection that seem to be pretty close to a debugger.

**Edit**: They are now called [CMake-server](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-server.7.html) and are part of CMake 3.7.

Answer (score 4):

Also, read about the env var `VERBOSE`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/VERBOSE.html

I used it this way:

```
export VERBOSE=defined
make
```

and got some more verbosity.

In other cases, edit `CMakeLists.txt` file to include the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

(Some post on this is https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/make-building-with-cmake-verbose ).

Also, there are useful `cmake` options controlling debug output, see the manpage: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 3.27, CMake comes with a built-in debugger. Start `cmake` with `--debugger` and it will expose debugging via the Debug Adapter Protocol.

Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debugger

Comment: note: this is already covered in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75701905/11107541