# How to Trace CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to examine what `cmake` is doing in a failing run?  For example, I have a program depending on libbacktrace, which I can link to by `gcc foo.c -lbacktrace`.  But when I write a `CMakeLists.txt` like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_library (BACKTRACE_LIBRARY backtrace)
message (BACKTRACE_LIBRARY=${BACKTRACE_LIBRARY})
```

and type `cmake <path>`, it prints out `BACKTRACE_LIBRARY=BACKTRACE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND`.

How do I go about figuring out where the problem is?  What commands is `cmake` executing before giving up on finding libbacktrace?  Is it executing anything at all?  In autoconf, the commands are all recorded in `config.log`, but `CMakeOutput.log` in this case is blank.  Likewise, `cmake --trace` only echoes the contents of `CMakeLists.txt` after a bunch of system cmake files, which is useless in this case.

Please note that I'm not looking for a way to make this particular invocation of `find_library` work - that's just an example.  My question is: I have a CMakeLists.txt that isn't working as expected; what tools exist to help me figure out where and why it's failing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is [no CMake debugger or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22803607/2799037)¹. What you can do is:

1. Read the output of CMake, sometimes it already gives hints like "missing INCLUDE_MYLIB_DIR"). Delete you CMakeCache.txt and/or remove the build directory, to be sure you don't miss output because the result was cached. Repeat and check whether caching had an influence. You get more warnings (those meant for the author/developer of the CMake script, not for the user) with `-Wdev`. More helpful options are `--warn-uninitialized`, `--warn-unused-vars` and `--check-system-vars`, see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake.1.html) for more details.
2. Check the generated files like the `CMakeCache.txt` and additional files you generate like a `config.h` or input files for Doxygen. Variables with values you expect different, are indicators for further research.
3. Have a look into CMakeError.log and CMakeOuput.log in the CMakeFiles sub-directory. Unfortunately, many test do not write into these files, but some do. For example C compiler runs put the compiler output there, which helps to find the problem with unintended flags or wrong (cross-)compilers.
4. Debug with [printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#printf_debugging). This means when you roughly know where you problem is located, output intermediate variables with `message`. That is helpful, when you don't know how a branch or a sub-expression (a part of a expression with AND or OR) is evaluated. Further you can put messages like "in branch where mylib version is > 3.2" inside to follow the workflow.
5. Reduce complexity. Throw everything out you don't know, until your problem vanishes. Add the stuff again until the problem reappears. Sometimes it is easier to start a new module to reproduce the problem with a minimal example. Surprisingly, this often helps to pinpoint the problem.
6. Debug with `--debug-output` (for debug output) `--trace` (complete trace) and `--trace-expand` (trace and expanded variables). For these it is extremely helpful to make progress with point 5., because otherwise the output will flood you.

¹Well, there are the steveire's [CMake Daemon Tools](https://steveire.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/cmake-daemon-for-user-tools/). I haven't used them myself, but they claim to offer possibilities for introspection that seem to be pretty close to a debugger.
**Edit:** They are now called [CMake-server](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-server.7.html) and are going to be part of CMake 3.7. You can expect that many tools and IDEs will pick this up and improve the way we develop CMake.

Answer (score 10):

Beside the mentioned flag `--trace` (and its variable-expanding sibling `--trace-expand`) there is `--debug-output`.

From the docs:

> `--debug-output`
> Put cmake in a debug mode.
>
> Print extra information during the cmake run like stack traces with message(send_error ) calls.

This might give you the desired info. Maybe in combination with `--trace`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `--trace-expand --debug-output` just echoes the lines in `CMakeLists.txt` in more different ways, which could be helpful in figuring out where `cmake` is failing.  But I'm more interested in the case where I already know which line is failing, and I want more information about what `cmake` is doing behind the scenes to fail there.

Comment: The only thing you can do is, based on the knowledge on what `find_library` does, is to manually (not within CMake) look in the paths as documented. `<VAR>-NOTFOUND` is all CMake will give you there within the scripts.