# How to strip trailing whitespace in CMake variable?

Tags: cmake, text-processing, uname

We are trying to improve the makefiles produced by CMake. For Clang, GCC and ICC, we want to add `-march=native`. The block to do so looks like:

```
# -march=native for GCC, Clang and ICC on i386, i486, i586, i686 and x86_64.
message(STATUS, "1")
message(STATUS, "Compiler: x${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}x")
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang" OR "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU" OR "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Intel")
    message(STATUS, "2")
    message(STATUS, "Machine: x${UNAME_MACHINE}x")
    if (("${UNAME_MACHINE}" MATCHES "i.86") OR ("${UNAME_MACHINE}" STREQUAL "x86_64"))
            message(STATUS, "3")
        if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
            add_definitions(-march=native)
        else()
            add_compile_options(-march=native)
        endif()
    endif()
endif()
```

The messages statements show the machine string from `uname` has a trailing newline:

```
STATUS,1
STATUS,Compiler: xGNUx
STATUS,2
STATUS,Machine: xx86_64
x
```

The block to produce `UNAME_MACHINE` is:

```
# We need the output 'uname -m' for Unix and Linux platform detection
#    Be prepared for i386-i686, amd64, x86_64, arm, arm64, armel, armhf,
#    mips, mips64, aarch32 and aarch64 (for starters)
set (UNAME_CMD "uname")
set (UNAME_ARG "-m")
execute_process(COMMAND ${UNAME_CMD} ${UNAME_ARG}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    RESULT_VARIABLE UNAME_RESULT
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE UNAME_MACHINE)
```

How do I strip the trailing newline from `UNAME_MACHINE` in CMake?

Or should I switch to a regex `matches`, which should not be affected by the newline?

Or, should I do something else?

---

We are attempting to support CMake 2.8 through Current. That roughly takes us back to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. There are some other operating systems around that time that push things back a little further. While `string(STRIP <string> <output variable>)` looks promising, [CMake does not supply version information with its documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/string.html), so we are not sure if it will meet requirements.

***EDIT*** it appears stripping does not work in 3.0.2, so it appears we need something else.

```
# Strip lead and trailing whitepasce
string(STRIP UNAME_MACHINE, UNAME_MACHINE)
```

Results in  the following (we expect `xx86_64x`):

```
STATUS,1
STATUS,Compiler: xGNUx
STATUS,2
STATUS,Machine: xUNAME_MACHINE,x
```

Adding dollar sign and curly braces, `${UNAME_MACHINE}`, results in the same original problem (the newline is still present).

Comment: `string(STRIP UNAME_MACHINE, UNAME_MACHINE)` — it could be that it failed because you included a comma (`,`) when parameters are separated by spaces in cmake.

Comment: CMake documentation [states](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/string.html#strip) `string(STRIP <string> <output variable>)` so your command should actually be `string(STRIP ${UNAME_MACHINE} UNAME_MACHINE)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This strips terminating newline in the variable <varname>:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "\n$" "" <varname> "${<varname>}")
```

Works for one of the project I involved to since CMake 2.8.

Answer (score 48):

`execute_process` has a flag for stripping trailing whitespace on either standard out or standard error (or both)

```
            [OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE]
            [ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE]
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html

Answer (score 15):

You can also use CMake's string [STRIP](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/string.html#strip) command which will remove leading and trailing spaces (and the trailing newline).

```
string(STRIP <string> <output variable>)
```

Comment: This is not true as with version 3.16 of cmake. First part is true (whitespace), second part, trailing newlines, is not.

Comment: cmake 3.16.9 / 3.22.3: works for leading and trailing spaces as well as newlines.
Checked with `set(a "\n abc \n")`, 
`string(STRIP ${a} a)`

Answer (score 4):

> Adding dollar sign and curly braces, ${UNAME_MACHINE}, results in the
>   same original problem (the newline is still present).

If you use curly braces you also need quote marks. EG:

```
string(STRIP "${UNAME_MACHINE}" UNAME_MACHINE)
```