# Why is the automatically found gcc compiler of CMake not right?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

This problem is related to **GCC** and **CMake**.

My original **CMakeLists.txt** is

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22.1)
project (Transformation)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

add_executable (Transformation main.cpp)
```

The **error** result is

```
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is unknown
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
[cmake]   The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     /usr/local/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin20-gcc-11.1.0
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
[cmake]   variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
[cmake]   the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

I have to set the path by myself. Then It builds successfully.

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin21-gcc-11")
```

Why is the default compiler in original situation x86_64-apple-darwin2**0**-gcc-11 **.1.0**? I don't have this file in /usr/local/bin. My gcc version is 11.2.0 and its name should be x86_64-apple-darwin2**1**-gcc-11.

(I've checked the relevant problem on "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is not a full path to an existing compiler tool" [How to find compiler path automatically in cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230175/how-to-find-compiler-path-automatically-in-cmake) but it seems not my situation)

This is my first time using CMake and gcc. I would be grateful if someone could help me(⑉꒦ິ^꒦ິ⑉).
Many thanks!!!

Comment: Mac OS aliases are generally not recognised by command line tools. They are neither symbolic links, nor hard links.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `darwin21` instead of `darwin20`?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Oh my bad. I didn't notice this.  I just copied the path from the error message and modified the suffix. Thank you!!! I've modified my problem. Could you have a look? (୨୧•͈ᴗ•͈)◞ᵗʱᵃᵑᵏઽ

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Thank you a lot! I had a typo in the alias and just corrected it. It works now. Does this mean Mac OS aliases can be recognized by command line tools? And could you have a look at my modified problem? Thanks!

Comment: @VoideNuit It's hard to tell the exact reason without knowing more about your situation. Is it possible that you installed earlier versions of gcc before (maybe automatically installed as a dependency of another program), and the path wasn't set correctly when you installed the new version? Or maybe the gcc path was set somewhere in a submodule without you noticing it?

Comment: @VoideNuit Also note that, currently you aren't building the project with the g++ you manually installed. Currently it says: `CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13`, which means you are using the Apple Clang instead of g++. You would need to manually set it to the g++ location similar to the way you set your C compiler.

Comment: @VoideNuit Also, it's often enough to use location like `/usr/local/bin/gcc-11` and `/usr/local/bin/g++-11`, or even `gcc-11` and `g++-11` as the path.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Thanks for your reminders. I knew nothing about makefile before and was just like a headless chicken. Thankfully, I've solved the problem by changing the kit. This is my first question posted on the Internet. I am grateful to have your patient answers. Many thanks!!!