# How can I "debug" the CMake executing process

Tags: cmake

I want to know all the details of the CMake process such as

- Which function it calls
- Which path it searchs
- Which caches it stores

I have tried `--debug-output`, and cmake-gui, but it's just not very detailed.

I don't like something that runs automatically without a report. It messes things up. For example, I have spent 2 hours to find out that CMake use Windows Registry "quietly" to get a path for "find_package()". This is really annoying.(Yes, if I had read EVERY word in the verbose document, I should have known it earlier)

Maybe the only way left for me is to look the source code of CMake? Actually, I have read CMake source code to fully understand the wield syntax of set()([Lists in CMake are just strings with semicolons delimiters](https://cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=2770))

Comment: `For example, I have spent 2 hours to find out that CMake use Windows Registry "quietly" to get a path for "find_package()".` - [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_package.html) for `find_package()` describes that (see step 7 of search algorithm).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, documentation on how-to debug CMake scripts itself could be better. So I requested/contributed to [a "Test and Debug" topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cmake/4098/test-and-debug) on SO Documentation. In short there are debug outputs for special tasks. For `find_package()` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cmake/4098/test-and-debug/21128/debug-find-package-errors) and for general information on file access/parsing see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I have noticed this in doc just after knowing CMake uses Registry. My fault. But on the other hand, I think as a programming language, you can't count on every user to fully understand its documents before starting using it.

Comment: `you can't count on every user to fully understand its documents before starting using it.` - When starting with CMake, it is sufficient to know that `find_package()` **finds things** installed by system-specific means. When you create your own packages or install 3d-party ones into several locations, it is not `starting with CMake` by any means. So you need to read documentation more thoroughly.

Comment: @usr1234567  I think CMake Daemon Tools is what I want.

Comment: @flm8620: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38869732/2799037, you might want to upvote that answer and close this question.

Comment: @usr1234567 Thx, I'm new here, not very familair with rules.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can look inside the scripts in the `share/cmake-3.x/Modules` folder for your particular package in order to find out how exactly it looks for the package, and what paths and registry keys it tries.

Or you can use the [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to spy on the cmake process to see what files and registry keys it tries to access.

Comment: Thx, Process Monitor is a cool thing to know