# Verbose cmake: How to get more diagnostics?

Tags: build, cmake, configure, infrastructure, verbose

I am getting some strange error from cmake :

```
loading initial cache file ../../Tweaks/compiler-rt/arm.txt
-- Performing Test COMPILER_RT_HAS_FPIE_FLAG
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    D:/Work/AcSo/Views/llvmSecond/build-arm/compiler-rt/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2

  when parsing string

    D:/Work/AcSo/Views/llvmSecond/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/cmake;D:/Work/AcSo/Views/llvmSecond/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/cmake/Modules;D:/Work/AcSo/Views/llvmSecond/llvm/cmake;D:\Work\AcSo\Views\llvmSecond\build-host\Release\lib\cmake\llvm

  Invalid character escape '\W'.


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Work/AcSo/Views/llvmSecond/build-arm/compiler-rt/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

All I could understand is that it gets a windows path somehow, and then complains about `\W` character sequence. Actually I've done what I could to give cmake Linux paths. So I don't know where the Windows path comes from. Nothing seems essential for this error in `CMakeOutput.log`

I would like to get more diagnostics from cmake, i.e. what and why it does, but searching for "cmake verbose" instead gives results about making the `make` verbose, not cmake itself.

Is there a way to force cmake verbose / get more diagnostics / debug or trace output? Or if you can tell what's the problem in my specific case, that's appreciated too.

Comment: Might be helpful, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22803607/2799037

Answer (score 7):

In this particular situation, cmake flags `--trace` and `--debug-output` suggested for the questions linked in the comments, were not as helpful as `--debug-trycompile` flag, which keeps such files as `CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt` (so they don't get removed when cmake fails).